# Reordering member declaration

Tags: c++, class

There is the quote from 3.3.7/1 in the C++ standard:

> If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid
>   program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is
>   required.

What does it mean? Can you get an example of such *reordering* declrartion?

Comment: One instance where the order of member declaration matters is the construction. When initializing values, you might initialize one dependent on another. If the order is wrong in the class, it could be initialized too early (before the other member is initialized).

Answer (score 3):

Consider this program:

```
double foo;
class Bar {
    std::vector<decltype(foo)> v;
    int foo;
};
```

*Reordering* `Bar::v` and `Bar::foo` like this:

```
double foo;
class Bar {
    int foo;
    std::vector<decltype(foo)> v;
};
```

Would yield an alternative program which is otherwise valid, thus the program violates the quoted rule.

(A version of) gcc chooses to isssue an error in the first case, but compiles with the second variant ("no diagnostic is required").

`std::vector<decltype(::foo)> v;` and `std::vector<decltype(Bar::foo)> v;` are valid alternatives (the latter is only possible if `Bar::foo` is declared first).

Comment: I think you meant the first line of both to be `double foo;`

Answer (score 0):

One example of the case is common error which you can get on object constructing.
Code variant 1 and 2 illustrate it.
Code variant 1:

```
class C
{
  C() : a1(0), a2(a1)
  {
  }

  int a1;
  int a2;
};
```

Code variant 2:

```
class C
{
  C() : a1(0), a2(a1)
  {
  }

  int a2;
  int a1;
};
```

Note that in variant 2 a1 and a2 members declaration order was cahnged. Good compilers will provide warning on code variant 2 : "members initialization is not as in declaration order".
The problem is that in code variant 2 program behaviour is undefined. Some compilers will generate code where a2 will be initialized with 0 (for example Visual Studio compiler as far as I can guess), some will generate code where a2 value will be undefined while in code variant 1 any compiler will provide correct code.
So it's the example you needed.

Comment: I'm not sure that counts as an alternate *valid* program.